# AngularJS break data into chunks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a table with data displayed in groups of 4 per row. I tried using angular.filter's [chunkBy](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#chunkby) but it displays nothing. I also tried creating a custom function to break the data into chunks

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=size) {
    newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i+size));
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

I am creating the table this way

```
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
            <td>
                <img ng-src="{{ fruit.img_url }}" lazy-src><br>
                <b>{{ fruit.name }}</b><br>
                <span style="color:green">{{ fruit.price_min }} </span> - <span style="color: red">{{ fruit.price_max }}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

However, this too creates an empty table. I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Could someone point out my mistake?

Comment: just check your fruits by writing {{ fruits | json }} before table. This will print data of fruits as json. So you will come to know that whether you are getting an array to loo on or not.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, you can also check your `$scope` with [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) extension

Comment: i found my mistake. the returned array is nested, i was only looping the outer one. not the inner one. thank you guys!

Comment: glad you found it yourself